# Installing a custom ROM on an Android device with broken screen

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, broken-screen

I have Samsung Galaxy Note5 (SM-N920C), but the screen is deadly broken and I need to

- update ROM
- enabled user debugging mode
- root device
- and move some apps to internal storage (like GPS JoyStick/ GPS spoofing)

I already rooted and install TWRP custom recovery, but the screen is fully deadly broken.

At present, I can control that device via scrcpy-win64-v2.1.1, but last week, the game I play was updated and no longer supports Android 7.0. I need to update that device's ROM.

My question is:

1. Can I update the ROM via fastboot or recovery mode at ADB or another tool?
2. If I can pass step 1, can I bypass the unauthorized to enable user debugging mode in the new ROM via fastboot or another way?
3. When passing step 2, can I re-root via step 2 (rooted via adb over fastboot or recovery mode)?

I know the problem is looking so hard, but I believe I can do it, but I don't know the command or tool to do it. If someone can help or share the trick with me, I very much thank you and hope this problem helps someone not lose an old phone device and make that can come back to working via computer control. Best regard.

Comment: On Samsung devices you usually only have to enable OEM unlock in your current OS and then install the new ROM via Odin/Heimdall (Samsung devices usually don't support ROM install via fastboot). The only problem is that after installing the custom ROM I think the bootloader detects the custom ROM and may ask if you really want to continue and delete your user data (not sure about this). At this stage scrcpy will never work, so you may have to use the phone blind without screen.